# Supremum of $\frac xn$

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

I want to know what's the supremum of $\frac{x}{n}$ as both $x$ and $n$ go to infinity. I was thinking of it being undefined but I dont know if that is the correct answer. Can somebody help?

Comment: That fraction can have any positive value you like for $x$ and $n$ arbitrarily large. So there is no supremum, or infimum.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "as both $x$ and $n$ go to infinity"?  There isn't a two variable limit as both go to infinity [as far as I know].

Comment: So I have this exercise where I need to find the supremum of |x/n|, x is in the domain (0, infinity) and n goes to infinity. I am a bit confused if we should consider both going to infinity or x is just an arbitrary number and the supremum is 0?

Comment: Can you share the exact wording of the problem? The answer depends on those details.

Comment: It sounds like $x$ is just some fixed number in $(0,\infty)$, and you are asked to consider $n$ ranging over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In fact I had to show the uniform convergence of the sequence, so I was showing sup|fn(x)-f(x)|, where the f(x)=0. Now, we are left with sup|fn(x)| = sup|x/n|, where x∈[0, infinity] and (fn) is from n=1 to infinity. Probably the expression is not good yet, but I'm also confused by myself, sorry about that.

Comment: So it sounds like what you actually want is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x > 0} \frac{x}{n}.$$ This would be zero if and only if $x/n \to 0$ uniformly on $x \in (0,\infty)$ as $n \to \infty$.  Does that sound like what you want?

Comment: Yes thats it. So that expression is zero? Well how do I show that fn(x)=(nx+1)/n^2 is uniformly convergent to zero, where x>0 and n goes to infinity? To show that its pointwise, I calculated the limit of it as n goes to infinity. And to calculate the uniform convergence I wanted to find  sup|fn(x)-f(x)| and see if it converges to zero. My main task was to determine if fn(x)=(nx+1)/n^2 is pointwise or uniform convergent. I tried to approach it by the description above but I'm not sure if I am any close to correct answer, because it's the first time doing these.

Comment: In short (referring to the expression I gave), no, its value is $\infty$, not zero.